# Create runnable jar with maven 3.1 using maven-dependency-plugin doesn't create runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, noclassdeffounderror

Using Maven 3.1
Eclipse Helios

**Aspekt:**

Try to create a runable jar file using maven-jar/dependency-plugins.

**Problem:**
After creating jar file and dependencies there are NoCLassDefFoundErrors when i try to start the jar file with command

```
  java -jar program.jar
```

But the Class/File is available in ./dependency-jars folder???
I Also tried following command:

```
  java -cp ./dependency-jars -jar program.jar
```

This didn't work, too.

**Question:**

Do you know why jvm can not find these classes? What is wrong?

**pom.xml:**

```
<build>
    <finalName>program</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>

                    <manifest>

                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>de.test.MainCLass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <outputDirectory>${package-target-folder}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javadoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <id>create-javadoc</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                        <outputDirectory>${package-target-folder}/docs</outputDirectory>
                        <reportOutputDirectory>${package-target-folder}/docs</reportOutputDirectory>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${package-target-folder}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>


                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**[UPDATE]**

The created MANIFEST.MF looks like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: ahausden
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
Class-Path: dependency-jars/spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-j
ars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar dependency-jars/spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEA
SE.jar dependency-jars/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars
/spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/spring-oxm-4.0.0.RELEASE
.jar dependency-jars/spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-j
ars/xstream-1.3.jar dependency-jars/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar dependency-ja
rs/jettison-1.1.jar dependency-jars/spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar depe
ndency-jars/spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/spring-e
xpression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/spring-batch-infrastructu
re-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar d
ependency-jars/spring-batch-test-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/co
mmons-io-1.4.jar dependency-jars/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar dependency-ja
rs/commons-pool-1.3.jar dependency-jars/commons-collections-3.2.jar d
ependency-jars/spring-test-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/javax.in
ject-1.jar dependency-jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar dependency-jars/sl
f4j-api-1.6.1.jar dependency-jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar dependency-jars/sp
ring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar dependency-jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar depend
ency-jars/mariadb-java-client-1.1.1.jar dependency-jars/hibernate-cor
e-4.3.1.Final.jar dependency-jars/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar dependen
cy-jars/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar dependency-jars/jbo
ss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar dependency-jars/dom4j-1.6
.1.jar dependency-jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar dependency-jars/hibernate-
commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar dependency-jars/hibernate-jpa-2.1
-api-1.0.0.Final.jar dependency-jars/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar dependen
cy-jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar dependency-jars/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar depend
ency-jars/hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar dependency-jars/hiber
nate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar dependency-jars/hibernate-jp
a-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar dependency-jars/javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar dep
endency-jars/commons-cli-1.3-20140221.042048-103.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.1.0
Main-Class: de.test.MainClass
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

And the last "line" is as line separator. Seems that the MANIFEST.MF file looks a little bit corrupt, doesn't it?

Comment: delete .m2 folder in filesystem,and again clean the project and rebuild.it works for me

Comment: Dependency pugin is not intended for such purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved the second/updated Problem:

I first startet to use eclipse with maven plugin to create the runable jar file. This runs in the described problems.

After all i tried to use maven 3.1 from console application and after all it works. 
Seems that eclipse maven plugin has some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's going on, but this is what my pom looks like for building a runnable jar using shade:

```xml
 <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>schema.xsd</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>stand-alone</shadedClassifierName>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:</exclude>
                            <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:</exclude>
                            <exclude>org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:</exclude>
                            <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:</exclude>
                            <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <finalName>MyFinalRunnableJarName</finalName>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>class.with.main.Method</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Ok. Seems that using shade-plugin solves the problem. But now there is another problem with injecting org.hibernate.SessionFactory. I will try to find solution. For now source problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the Shade suggestion, this worked for me in create a executable .jar with Spring dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide entry into manifest file:

```
Main-Class: YourClassWithMainMethod
```

And also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218704/cant-create-a-runnable-jar-file-via-eclipse). So you can make it manually and see the difference.

If `dependency-jars` is a directory also try:

```
java -cp ./dependency-jars/* -jar program.jar
```

I still cannot post comments, so please show what are these NoCLassDefFoundErrors.
And have you tried to do the same jar file manually from Eclipse and see the difference?

You have dependency dependency-jars/commons-cli-1.3-20140221.042048-103.jar in your manifest but you wrote you have SNAPSHOT version in directory. And there is only commons-cli:commons-cli:20040117.000000 in maven central.

@robermann please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/using-wildcard-for-classpath) (to work it should be in double quotes though)

Comment: Already did. MainClass in MANIFEST.MF is correct. Problem is also that i have to create the jar with maven. There are no alternatives

Comment: '-cp ./dependency-jars/*' cannot work, jar names have to be explicited

Comment: @Andrei Kuziakov thank you, I missed that java 6's enhancement :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
             org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
         -->
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Ok, that was a good solution. but now i have another problem with spring that context can not find declarationi of "beans". But thanks for the first solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your java version, launched at command line, is equal or greater than that used by maven when compiling? try `java -version`

Comment: Yes already checked. I have only one java version on computer and its exactly the same as i developed with

Comment: So, which is the class with NoCLassDefFoundErrors ? de.test.MainCLass?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)

Comment: But the jar file commons-cli-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar (in which the missing class is inside) still remains in ./dependency-jars folder

Comment: It seems org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException is not in maven: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cc%3A%22org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException%22

Comment: It is because in eclipse the Application works correct. And the depedency is maintented by maven

Comment: Could you give artifact & group id of your commons-cli-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
   <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  ---
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>apache.snapshots</id>
   <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>central</id>
   <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

Comment: yes. Using jvm Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode) and its excatly the same as i developed with. And the execution environment is the same on the same server

Answer (score 0):

via command line, go to the parent dir of "dependency-jars" and run: `java -jar program.jar`

Comment: should contain the file './dependency-jars/commons-cli-1.3-20140221.042048-103.jar'

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to create jar file of any maven project.

mvn clean compile install