# mapreduce code working on eclipse but not on cluster

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, opennlp

I am working on code which uses openNLP. My code runs on eclipse perfectly, but when I run its jar on a cluster, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/util/ObjectStream
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the OpenNLP jar available and in your classpath on your tasks. There are several options:

- `-libjars` and HADOOP_CLASSPATH, see [Using the libjars option with Hadoop](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/)
- 'fat jar': build a jar that contains all the necessary jars, submit the fat jar instead
- install the 3rd party jars on all nodes (ie. make the cluster '3rd party aware')
- use the HDFS [distributed cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) and download the necessary jars in your code

For a lengthier discussion see [How-to: Include Third-Party Libraries in Your MapReduce Job](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/)

Comment: You can use maven shade to put the OpenNLP jar in the "fat jar"  this post shows an example of shade

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096909/create-runable-jar-with-maven-3-1-using-maven-dependency-plugin-dosnt-create-ru/22097164#22097164